# Python and MySQL: If catch deadlock error, is everything rolled back?

Tags: python, mysql

I'd like to catch a MySQL deadlock error and then retry the failed query. But, do I have to redo every query since the transaction started, or just the one in the try/catch? I'm not sure whether the deadlock error causes everything to be rolled back.

This is performed in Python using raw mysql queries.

```
insert into table_1 values...
insert_into_table_2 values ...
try:
   delete from table_1 where ...
except: # set to catch deadlock error
   # Can I just retry the delete statement, or do I also have to do the inserts again?

# commits at end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole transaction is rolled back.

Here's the relevant and helpful MySQL documentation:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-deadlock-detection.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-deadlocks.html